# How to create and construct a class from another class in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, xsd, unmarshalling

Is it possible to create a class (starting from nothing) and construct/write his content from another class?

For example, I got a class `StartingClass`. And with the methods of this class I want to create `ConstructClass` (that doesn't exist yet). Inside `StartingClass` methods I want to specify the content of `ConstructClass`, like the class it extends, its attributes, its methods.

I need to do this because i need to create new classes from generated classes and unmarshalled xml datas.

I thought about editing a file with `.java` extension but it's not very clean.

Comment: Looks like you want to implement a code generator. You make take a look into some template engines for java.

Comment: Maybe Java Reflection?  Lets you inspect classes and their insides at runtime

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate classes dynamically using Java. [Javassist](https://www.javassist.org/) is one way to do it. [Cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) is another way; there's [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) too and I'm sure there are a few more. However, I'd suggest you to rethink why you need to do this. It's not recommended to do this, because Java is a static language. Are you sure it's the best one to use for your use case? And also, dynamic classes heavily depend on the use of Object and reflection in order for them to work.

If you have any clue what your classes might be like, something like a factory pattern can help you much more to process the XML files. Or else perhaps use an `Object[]` or `Map<Object, Object>`

If you must, try looking into Javassist or cglib like solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the JavaCompiler, you can create and compile at runtime. This example below shows how to do that and you can parametrize the generation of the files and folders and also read the content of one existent Java file as a template for your generation.

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class StackOverFlowClassFileGenerationTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ClassGenerationTest.java");
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
    ps.println("public class ClassGenerationTest {\n");
    ps.println("\t\tpublic static void main(String[] args) {\n");
    ps.println("\t\t\t\tSystem.out.println(\"Testing the class generation at runtime\");\n");
    ps.println("\t\t}\n}\n");
    ps.close();
    fos.close();

    JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    String javacOpts[] = {"ClassGenerationTest.java"};
    if (javac.run(null, null, null,  javacOpts) != 0) {
      System.out.println("Error");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Success");
    }
  }
}
```

It's possible to do something similar easily using [jOOR](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR) version 0.9.8, which will offer some methods to compile classes at runtime. You can check this [post](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and) to understand better.